# Angular2 - how to return service error to main application component

Tags: angular, service

I have a service that gets a json from http

I created a dialog for errors in my main app, but I dont understand how you give back the potential error to the applicationi so it displays it on the web page

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class TranslateService 
{
    constructor(private http:Http) 
    {
        this.http.get("some.json").map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe( 
                res => 
                {
                    ....
                },
                error =>
                {
                    console.log(error); <<<< how to give this error to the main application component ?
                },
            );
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: can you paste the code of your component also?

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a custom [global error handler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html):

```
 class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
   private errorSubject:Subject<any>;
   public errorEvent$: Observable<any>;
   constructor() {
       this.errorSubject = new Subject<any>();
       this.errorEvent$ = this.errorSubject.asObservable();
   }

  handleError(error) {
    // do something with the exception
    this.errorSubject.next(error);
  }
}
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}]
})
class MyModule {}
```

Then in your error dialog component:

```
class ErrorDialog implements OnInit {
    constructor(private errorHandler: MyErrorHandler) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.errorHandler.errorEvent$.subscribe(t=> {
            // show dialog here
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: neat,.... btw I dont understand why it's called an observer since its the one that will provide data to the stream, not the part that will subscribe and "listen" to the observable

Comment: what is the @ before private ?