# How to catch exception during interpolation?

Tags: angular

I would like to catch any exception which may happen during interpolation.
Interpolation happen outside of the control of my code. 
Is there a way to install something like an global exception handler?

I have the following objectives:

First of all I want to prevent a stop of the app. It is absolutely inacceptable to stop working after throwing an exception. Stopping an app is totally unprofessional.

Second, I would like to log such cases to the server to investigate the cause for later improvements. In general there is no access to users browser console log

Comment: I would implement a global exception handler:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435554/angular2-how-to-return-service-error-to-main-application-component/42435775?noredirect=1#comment72024897_42435775

Comment: It should be clarified what is 'interpolation' here. A working example would help. If these are compilation errors, they can be logged but cannot be recovered from.